# How to tell if XML parser has finished parsing file?

Tags: node.js, xml, parsing

I'm parsing a 2GB+ xml file, initially i process(multi-thread) records one by one.

But single insert sql query to DB it's too slow(DB bottle neck) hence I need to create a mass insert query/cvs file after going through the xml document. But unlike java, in nodejs i can't tell if the documents has been fully parse.

Been working on it for 12hrs+, would be great if anyone can help me out. Perhaps try other xml libraries ? or just use good old java.

```
 var bigXml = require('big-xml');  
     reader = bigXml.createReader('dblp.xml', /^(article)$/, { gzip: false });

 var count = 0;
  var temp = [];
  reader.on('record', async function (record) {

  console.log("Processing article:" + count);

  count++;

   var pubBody = importPubBuilder(record); 
   temp.push(pubBody);
  //taking temp Array to csv when finish reading file

  });

  reader.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

function importPubBuilder(record) {

  var body = {};
  body.pubkey = record.attrs.key;
  body.mdate = record.attrs.mdate;
  body.title = null;
  body.ee = null;
  body.url = null;

  if (record.children.find(obj => {    return obj.tag == "title"  }) != null)  {
    body.title = record.children.find(obj => {    return obj.tag == "title"  }).text;
  }

  if( record.children.find(obj => {    return obj.tag == "ee"  }) != null){
    body.ee =record.children.find(obj => {    return obj.tag == "ee"  }).text
  }
  if( record.children.find(obj => {    return obj.tag == "url"  }) !=null){
    body.url = record.children.find(obj => {    return obj.tag == "url"  }).text
  }

  return body

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated added close event emitter when file stream close. Fork with improvement at npm big-xml-notify [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-xml-notify)